# how create get url from Visual Studio 2015 for Windows Iot in app C#

Tags: c#, http-get, iot, windows-10-iot-core, windowsiot

How create get url from Visual Studio 2015 for Windows Iot in app C# (Universal App Windows)

`Getreponse();` from c# 2015 is deprecated

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://XXX/online?check=useronline");
request.Method = "GET";
using (var response = request.GetResponse())
using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
```

[image]

Comment: What url are you looking for?

Comment: get players connected from website "http://myurl.com/online?check=useronline" output 200 only text no html.

Comment: Please try to be specific about your question.  We can't guess what's your application about... ex: how player connect to your server and what you have tried so far.

Comment: Ok my post is updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Universal App Platform has a great class for HTTP.

HttpClient has all you need to get a web resource with a very few lines of code.

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var content = await client.GetStringAsync(new Uri("http://danvy.tv"));
```

Check the details here

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.web.http.httpclient.getstringasync

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look this example.

https://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/samples/BlinkyWebServer.htm

all request receiving from one function so easily use reqex and make your web service.